# trigger click event manually in dynamic table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created dynamic table using javascript,But the problem is I want to mannually trigger click event of dynamically added text boxes on change event of dynamically added dropdown

Comment: show your relevant code

Comment: Do you have javascript functions associated to the click handlers? Then why don't you call the click handler function, instead of triggering click event through the browser?

Answer (score 2):

if you're using jQuery you can use .trigger('click') on the element that has the click listener, if you aren't using jQuery you can do more or less the same with .dispatchEvent():

```
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox'); 
  var cancelled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pure javascript

Try this

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.border=1
table.cellPadding=10
table.cellSpacing=0
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  var td3 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.innerHTML=i+1;
  var tb = document.createElement("input");
  tb.type="text";
  //Binding Event to textbox
  tb.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert("Clicked")
  })
  var ddl = document.createElement("select");
  for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
    var ddlOption=document.createElement("option");
    ddlOption.value=j+1;
    ddlOption.innerHTML=j+1;
    ddl.appendChild(ddlOption);
  }
  //Binding Event to dropdownlist
  ddl.addEventListener('change',function(){
    alert(this.value);
  })
  
  td2.appendChild(tb);
  td3.appendChild(ddl);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  tr.appendChild(td3); 
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById("MyDiv").appendChild(table)
```

```html
<Div id="MyDiv">
  
</Div>
```